# Missing indexes for ALL stored procs

Tags: sql, database-administration

Is there a way to check for missing indexes for ALL of the stored procs, or am I stuck going one by one?

Background,
there has been no real DBA in the office, ever, and the database has been growing for more than 20 years.  I have been the closest thing to a DBA, and I have some skill, but it is not my first focus.

Now I have been tasked with looking at the stored procs and checking indexes.  I am not even looking at optimizing or updating the stored procs, other than to bring them to a 2016 standard if needed (we did that a couple of years ago, updated the "Compute" and *= queries as needed).

So the question is, Is there a way to check for missing indexes for ALL of the stored procs, or am I stuck going one by one?

Comment: I’m nit dure what you are asking as stored procs don’t have indexes, tables do. In any case, what’s your definition of a missing index - as in most cases indexes are optional?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Using MS 2018 SQL Server Manager.
@NickW, you are correct, stored procs don't have indexes, but the queries inside run against the tables, and having indexes speeds up the query.

Comment: Yes, but you don’t normally index every possible column used in a query. A DBA, possibly  in conjunction with a query analyser, would use their experience to identify slow queries, determine how best to add indexes to speed up a query and would test the result to confirm the performance had improved. So as there is no way of automatically determining the best indexes to apply to a query, how are you defining that an index is missing?

Comment: I pull up the stored proc, remove the "Alter procedure" line and replace it with "Declare", then I remove all of the default values for the variables, and finally remove the "AS".  After that, I do the Estimated Execution Plan.  If it identifies an Index that can be increase the speed by 50% or more, then I do it.